# How to make an SVG animation reset

Tags: html, svg

started getting into SVG animations recently, so what I'm trying to do is make this circle go to the center of the rect and back, which it does the first time then the backing animation keeps repeating, here is the code:

```
    <svg style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: yellow;" width="750" height="500">
    <circle id="kruzic" cy="250" cx="0" r="40" fill="blue">
        <animate attributeName="cx" attributeType="XML" from="-50" to="335" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="cx" attributeType="XML" from="335" to="-50" begin="2s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a list of values:

```html
<svg style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: yellow;" width="750" height="500">
    <circle id="kruzic" cy="250" cx="0" r="40" fill="blue">
        <animate attributeName="cx" attributeType="XML"  dur="4s" values="-50; 355; -50;" repeatCount="indefinite" />

    </circle>
</svg>
```